# SOLR (lucene) XML support

Tags: solr, full-text-search

Regarding SOLR as a fulltext search engine, I am looking for documentation about the support it has for XML documents.
[1] Does it have any support in XPath (from point of view of asking about a "Field" using XPath notion) ?
[2] Does it have any support in XQuery queries ?
[3] Does it has hierarchy support ?
For example,
Assuming I got the following XML

```
<A>
  <B>kdflsdk</B>
  <C>
    <B>222</B>
  </C>
</A>
```

is there a way in which I can query on 222 which is inside the C tags, or query on kdflsdk which is in the limits of the B element ?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for documentation about the support it has for XML
>   documents.

You are better off using `XsltUpdateRequestHandler` [1] to handle arbitrary XML documents and `DIH XPathEntityProcessor` [2] for batch indexing of XML documents. Both of these techniques are well documented --for starters, the wiki pages should be sufficient for your immediate needs.

> Does it have any support in XPath (from point of view of asking about
>   a "Field" using XPath notion) ? Does it have any support in XQuery
>   queries ?

You might want to dig into the basics of how Solr indexing works [3]... but basically, when you ingest documents to a Solr index, you are making it searchable by Solr; that is the reason why Solr has a specific ingest format [4]. Forget about your source files' structure once you index them.

> Does it has hierarchy support ? For example, Assuming I got the
>   following XML

Solr handles this for you implicitly; think 'Solr' when you index your data --you issue queries using the Solr API once you index data.

> is there a way in which I can query on 222 which is inside the C tags,
>   or query on kdflsdk which is in the limits of the B element ?

A couple of things to note here: 
1. You flatten your XML file format during ingestion into Solr index 
2. Solr accepts HTTP requests and so you would probably rename `/A/B/C/B` to some different name since you already have a second-level B tag and then issue an HTTP request similar to the one below to get value of third-level B tag that machies 'kdflsdk'....

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=B:kdflsdk&fl=CB`

You MUST read this [5] to get a sense of how to query Solr.

[1] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler 
[2] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor 
[3] http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html 
[4] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages 
[5] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Answer (score 0):

You can index the data using [DIH for XML](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2BAC8-HTTP_Datasource) and use Solr to search over the fields.